# How to make a simple login page in using a bootstrap and JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Hello everyone I am starting to learn step by step in web programming. I am planning to create a simple log-in form using a bootstrap and Javascript. What is the way to achieve it?.

Comment: This is a very broad question - are you actually asking how to implement the log in/sessions on the server too, or just the HTML for Bootstrap front end? Either way, those are very broad questions - SO is for solving specific programming problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this :)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#loginForm").submit(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      if ($("#userEmail").val() != '' && $("#userPassword").val() != '') {
           if ($("#userEmail").val() == 'test@gmail.com' && $("#userPassword").val() == 'test') {
              window.location.href = './home.html'; 
           } else {
               alert('invalid username password');
           }
      } else {
        alert('username or password cann\'t be blank');  
      }
   });
});
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" style="margin-top:30px">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading"><h3 class="panel-title"><strong>Sign in </strong></h3></div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <form role="form" id="loginForm">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Username or Email</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" style="border-radius:0px" id="userEmail" placeholder="Enter email">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password <a href="/sessions/forgot_password">(forgot password)</a></label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" style="border-radius:0px" id="userPassword" placeholder="Password">
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-default">Sign in</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How can I write a code in JS that if uname = uname and pw = pw then access the first page?. if wrong prompt error.

Comment: @MsAllWednesday: don't ask for writing code to someone direct, first you try and show what you have done so far, stackoverflow is network where people will help you in your problems, they will not write code for you, make sence ?

Answer (score 0):

Start from tutorials, there are plenty of them on the internet eg. https://scotch.io/tutorials/authenticate-a-node-js-api-with-json-web-tokens

When your server will be ready you can easly add login formule to it.